# What wattage solar panel required for AC 1000 watts

Tags: dc, ac, solar-cell, watts

If my house load is 1000 Watts AC/220V, then 1000 Watts DC/12V solar panels is not enough. What wattage solar panel would be required for AC 1000 watts?

Comment: One thing not mentioned but relevant, the wattage may be close but the amperage is vastly different. Whereas the AC side at 1000 watts is only 9.0 amps, the DC side will be 83.0 amps. Keep this in mind when setting up your system. That's a rough estimate so be sure and do the math yourself with your actual numbers when determining your wire size.

Answer (score 4):

If the average power consumed by your household is 1 kW, you'll need about 6 kW of solar panels to supply this. This is based on the fact that in most environemnts, solar panels can produce their full power for about 4 hours per day, on average.

You'll also need a storage system that can store enough energy for several days of poor sunlight, and an inverter that can supply the *peak* power that your household needs at any given time.

Comment: This is actually quite a bit on the low side. Conversion of solar cell output to battery storage is nowhere near 100%. Conversion of battery output is maybe 85%. Not only do you need storage for several days of cloudy weather, you need excess solar panel capacity to make up the energy not received during those cloudy days.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: I agree with everything you said. All I was really trying to do was bring some of the first-order issues in system design to the OP's attention.

Comment: Yup. And I gleefully expanded on them. Didn't mean to seem harsh, it's just that I've seen so may folks who wildly underestimate what they need for this sort of problem that it brings out the worst in me.

Comment: WRB/DT - Work out what mean daily kWh hot water load is desired - provide for that directly from PV. Save on grid tie costs and batteries. Hot water serves as a time shifting energy store. This can be a very cost effective way of using first part of a PV installation until energy provided gets > hot water load often. [[MPPT PV to hot water can be done with PWM to resistor with cap on PV to hold Vpanel during PWM cycle. ]]

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Who said anything about hot water? If that's what you need, you should heat the water directly with the sun; PV is a very inefficient way to go about it.

Comment: @Dave Tweed - I said :-). Intuition tells you it makes little sense. 'Do the maths' shows that it's on of the best uses of solar PV going - 'IF' "distortions" such as FITs are ignored, and maybe then depending on how large the FIT rates are as a % of retail cost and 'IF' night heating rates are not massively discounted (and they are not, in many situations). If HW (hot water) load **across a 24 hour day** is > PV capacity ACROSS the insolation period and as long as tank is as lagged as it should be you 'save' the cost of heating the water at going rate. You don't need a grid tie inverter ...

Comment: ... and can do MPPT PV to low voltage element energy transsfer at very close to 100 efficiency. There are NO header tanks, plumbing, pumps, water pipes, water feed, Legionaires disease protection in header, ... . The formal DCF payback in a level playing field market is better than for PV grid-tie and about as good a rate of return as anything as safe that you can  invest in that is as low risk. As you seasonal PV capacity starts to rise above typical water heating load the sums change. If you have something to do with the energy the HW part still makes sense unless FITs massively skew things.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Sure, heating water is a good way to use excess PV energy -- assuming you need hot water. But unless you have a way of converting hot water back into electricity efficiently, it doesn't address the OP's question about the supply of electricity.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes - you are correct - hot water is not a good starting point for making electricity from. Molten steel is better but harder to handle :-).  But, surprisingly, I you have a grid connected house and install solar PV with the aim of reducing your power bill then (given the 2 assumptions above) solar pv is actually often a good FIRST use of the solar PV and not just if there is any left over. This is because it replaces grid electricity unit for unit, can get 95% + efficiency PV to water and allows energy storage. | High FITs and good night rates may wreck this.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: Ah, but that assumes you were using electricity for heating in the first place. In my house, all major heating loads (including hot water, clothes dryer and cooking) are supplied by natural gas.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve a 1000W output you would need 1000W + losses imposed by the inverter's efficiency.

Say the inverter is 85% efficient, then from a 1000W input you would get 850W out.  So, to achieve 1000W output you would need a minimum of ( \$\frac{1000}{85} × 100\$ ) = 1176.47W.

Of course, the output of the solar panel is dependant on the incoming sunlight, so you would most probably want to provide considerably more than that to allow for the odd cloud.